# Check for Multidimensional Array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i started today on coding with Google tables and JS. Now i got a small issue:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
    If(data[row][0].length <= 0) { //Error Line
      Logger.log(data[row][0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Now im receiving an error tht im missing a ; but i dont get why. Hope someone can help me with that

Comment: `if` and not `If`

Comment: I reached this point too but i need to know whats wrong

Comment: *an error tht im missing a ;* - are you sure that is the error you receive? You should receive something like `Uncaught ReferenceError: If is not defined`

Comment: also, `.length` of an array/string will never be less than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `missing ;` error because of the "If" typo that the other commenters pointed out. The JS parser thinks that `If(...)` is function call and is immediately followed by `{`. This shouldn't happen, you should have a terminated statement (or a valid "if" clause...) before beginning of a block (`{ ... }`).

Comment: his first version was kinda unclear but now it makes a lot of sense, annoying to waste that much time on sth like that. Thanks for the help